# Laravel find record in another table associated with $data

Tags: laravel, view, controller

I am looking over some laravel code and I have a few questions regarding the code. In the view, I see a piece of code "$data->profile->age". Does this code automatically find the profile record in the profile table associated with the $data? How does it find the associated profile?

Controller:

```
return view('new-design.pages.influencer.info')
                ->withData($data)
```

View:

```
$data->profile->age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It finds the associated profile using the relations you definied in your Profile model

> Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model:

Here's a simple example from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) to help you understand:

Let's say you have a `posts` table and a `comments` table:

We need to define a relationship between this two tables.

> A one-to-many relationship is used to define relationships where a single model owns any amount of other models. For example, a blog post may have an infinite number of comments.

**Note:** you must have a foreign key in your `comments` table referencing the `posts` table, like `post_id`, in this case, if you use a different name you should inform that in your relation:

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the  **Comment** model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it `with _id`. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the  Comment model is `post_id`.

In your **Post** model you could do:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

And in your **Comment** model you should define the inverse relationship

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to access all comments from a post you just need to get the relation:

```
$post = Post::find($id); // find a post
$post->comments; // This will return all comments that belong to the given post
```

So, you basically access them as if they were a property from the model, as said in the documentation

In your view you could do something like this:

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
{
 {{$comment->text}} 
}
@endforeach
```

This example will print every comment text from the Post we get in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon in your model for $data there is a function called profile. From that it is getting the equivalent profile.

Example: Imagine you have a model called phone and you want to find the user who owns it. You can write the following function in your model.

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

And in the view you may write something like

```
$phone->user->name
```

Now, behind the scene laravel will go to the phone and get the value from `user_id` for that phone. (If the foreign key is located in different column you can specify that too). Then laravel will find the users table with that `user_id` and retrieve the row. Then show the name on view.

Now if there is a complex query you can also write a function for that in the model.